# Best alternatives for extracting last integer data from given string from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to extract only the integer data part at the end of this string.

Example: `/coronavirus/07-2020covid19/**58241**'

My code:

```
select  
    reverse(substring(reverse('/coronavirus/07-2020covid19/58241'),
                      1 ,
                      patindex('%/%', reverse('/coronavirus/07-2020covid19/58241')) - 1))
```

Output: `58241`

Execution stats for above statement:

[image]

I just want to know the best way of doing this as I have around 25.5M rows. So I am basically looking for optimal fast solution with lesser load on SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to split the string:

```
select s.value
from string_split('/coronavirus/07-2020covid19/58241', '/') s
where '/coronavirus/07-2020covid19/58241' like '%/' + s.value;
```

If you also want to throw in that it is a number, you can add:

```
s.value not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

If this is a column in a table, you would use `apply`:

```
select t.*, s.value
from t cross apply
     split_part(t.col) s
where t.col like '%/' + s.value;
```

Another method looks for the last `'/'`.  I would use `stuff()`:

```
select stuff(str, 1, len(str) - charindex('/', reverse(str)) + 1, '')
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I think these are MySQL syntaxs. well I can try for SQL server

Comment: `STUFF` is a T-SQL function, @Shivkumarkondi . `SPLIT_PART`, however, is not, and Gordon seems to inconsistantly provide it with one or two parameters. Perhaps he means `STRING_SPLIT`, however, that requires 2 parameters, like in his first example.

Comment: @Shivkumarkondi . . . I don't know why my fingers types `split_part()` instead of `string_split()`.  The question is tagged SQL Server and I intended for this to be a SQL Server answer.